# Has anyones had KML opacity issues lately?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, opacity

I have a basic County (poygon) kml and last week it was working perfect.  Today I looked on my site and notice that the opacity for the kml is not working in any browser.  I tried opening it up in google earth and it works fine but on the map using the google maps api V3 on my website the kml is not giving me 100% opacity. Does anyone know of any steps I can take to track down what is happening with my KML?

The link for the download kml is http://www.gbnrtc.org/files/2813/3434/9208/GBNRTC_Boundary.kml

Comment: It's not too clear what behavior should happen. Should the polygon be solid or semitransparent? When I tried adding a `new google.maps.KmlLayer` with your kml, I saw the shape cover up the map, and it was solid, nothing could be seen under it (opacity=1.0). Are you using another method of adding the kml layer?

Comment: It basically should be just the county outline. When I use in google earth its a gray outline that is completely transparent which is what I want.  I want it to outline the county showing the map. I am adding the kml layer by basically adding this code...           

GBNRTC = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.gbnrtc.org/files/2813/3434/9208/GBNRTC_Boundary.kml', {preserveViewport:true});

GBNRTC.setMap(map)

Comment: Importing my kml into a fusiontable and adding that to the code, seems to work the correct way. But once again when I export the fusiontable as a kml and add that back in I lose the outline again, weird.

Comment: Thanks for the report. This sounds like a bug and I have filed a ticket to have it looked into.

Comment: Thanks. Please let me know if this issue has been fixed.  Right now the work around for this is just to turn the kml into a fusion table and that works.  But I don't want to turn all of my kmls to fusion tables yet because of custom marker icon limitations.